# What's an efficient way to perform operations with NA values in R?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, na

I would like to perform operation on a data frame which ignores lines with `NA` values (However, I don't want to remove the rows with `NA` values, I still want them in the data frame). I have actually already managed to do this, but I am after a more computationally efficient method since mine is very, very slow.

Let's say for instance we have a data frame as follows:

```
Number    |   Object
  10      |   Car
  11      |   Book
  12      |   Pen 
  13      |   Door   
  NA      |   Computer    
  14      |   Cup
  15      |   Book
```

I wish to perform an operation on this data frame where I would like to access the previous/next `Object` in the data frame but only on the condition that the `Number` column does not have an `NA` value for that index. For example, let's say I am at index 4 in the `Number` column (which means that the 'Number' is 13 and the `Object` is Door), and I want to access the next object such that there is no `NA` value in the `Number` column. This means that since index 5 has `NA` in the `Number` column, I would instead go to index 6 since it has 14 in the `Number` column and therefore I will have Cup as the object instead of computer.

Now, as mentioned above, I've actually already implemented one such method to perform this task through basically using a combination of functions such as `which()` and `min()` and `max()` etc. but I am after a method/function which is much more computationally efficient since I have a lot of data to work with (the method I am using is very slow and inefficient since it needs to check through a large number of values). Is there a more computationally efficient way to accomplish this task? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify exactly what you have (code+data) and what you want. The process you're describing seems iterative which is usually not the most efficient in R

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
a$Object[!is.na(a$Number)][i+1]
```

where `a` is your dataframe and `i` is the index you are currently at.

Comment: That looks better, but is there any way to modify it such that it doesn't need to look at the entire column each time I use `is.na()`?

Answer (score -1):

I'd advise you to look into the **na** function.

Here's a good source to start with:
[HOW DOES R HANDLE MISSING VALUES?](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-missing-values/)

Have a look at the complexity of below code:

```
a<-data.frame(c(15,25,35,NA,55),c("a","b","c","d","e"))
colnames(a)<-c("Number","Object")
a
i = 1
while(i<length(a$Number)-1){
  if (!is.na(a$Number[i])){
     if (!is.na(a$Number[i+1])){
        print(a$Object[i+1])
        i = i + 1
        }
     else{
        print(a$Object[i+2])
        i = i + 2 
        }
  }
}
```

Of course, you could deploy one-liner functions.

Comment: That does look to be useful, but it looks like it creates a new copy of the original data frame except without the `NA` values so it would take up memory in that case. Ideally I want a method or function which will basically look at an element, ignore if it is `NA` and then move onto the next element

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but could you explain the purpose of the code? Or rather, why you added it to your reply?

Comment: Have you tried the snippet which I shared with you? If not, do try and then let me know your suggestions.